# Symfony 2 forwarding requests to another controller with changed content

Tags: symfony

I want to forward a request to another controller using something like this:

```
$controller_response = $this->forward( 'MyBundle:Clients:getClients' );
```

That works fine, but I need to updated the request to have different content, I can't work out  what method I should be using, the following don't work:

```
$request->content->set('new content');
$request->set('content', 'new content');
$request->setContent('new content');
```

Is it even possible to do this? If not I could create a brand new request and add it in as an argument, I'd rather avoid doing that though if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the Response content with the `setContent` method.

```
$response->setContent('<html>Hello</html>');
```

You can also alter the request

```
$request->request->set('key', 'value');
$request->query->set('key', 'value');
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setContent()

Comment: still doesn't seem to work for content, everything else seems to work fine (headers, query, etc). My solution so far is to manually create a brand new request with Request::create then pass it through as an argument. It works but it would be nicer to just override the current request content.

Answer (score 1):

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$newContent = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$request->initialize($request->query->all(), $request->request->all(), $request->attributes->all(), $request->cookies->all(), $request->files->all(), $request->server->all(),  $newContent);
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a great way of doing it, but this worked for me.